# Find Eigen on OS X

Tags: ros, eigen, homebrew, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm currently using [this method](https://github.com/g/grizzly/blob/hydro-devel/grizzly_msgs/CMakeLists.txt):

```
project(grizzly_msgs)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED)
find_package(Eigen REQUIRED)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include ${Eigen_INCLUDE_DIRS} 
  DEPENDS eigen
)
```

This works great in Ubuntu and on the buildfarm, but gave me a problem when I attempted to compile under OS X / Indigo / homebrew—unable to find the `EigenConfig.cmake` module. I have Eigen 3.2 installed via homebrew, but it doesn't seem to supply a cmake module. Is there some better way to do this which will work for Ubuntu and other OSes?

---

Update: Looks like the FindEigen.cmake module is right there in the usual place:

/opt/ros/indigo/share/cmake_modules/cmake/Modules/FindEigen.cmake

Do I need to build_depend on cmake_modules in order for cmake to find these?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/144996/find-eigen-on-os-x/) by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1153 on 2014-03-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ah yes, need to build_depend on it and then find it. Details here:

https://github.com/ros/cmake_modules/blob/0.3-devel/README.md

---

Originally posted by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) with karma: 1153 on 2014-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-03-26**:
Yes, this is in the Indigo migration guide: http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Migration#catkin